# Not able to parse json request in node js

Tags: json, node.js, angular

I have below data in angular that I am passing to node API. Here I have one JSON data that I am passing to node API using POST method.

```
var data = {
      "que": {
        "id": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "option": [
          {
            "opt_id": "",
            "opt_txt": "02-10-1995"
          }
        ]
      }
    };

let questionData = JSON.stringify(data);

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

return this._http.post(url', questionData, options)
    .map(x => x.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

In node code I am getting below data in req.body:
req without parse:  `{ '{"que":{"id":1,"status":1,"option":':{'{"opt_id":"","opt_txt":"02-10-1995"}': '' } }`

I tried with parsing the req.body data but I am not able to get actual string as it adds single quote at starting of string and close it just after option and another single quotes starts just before opt_id.

My parsing code is like below:

```
JSON.parse(req.body)
```

In app.js I have

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Please help me out to get proper json at node side.

Comment: Don't stringify your data before passing them to angular http's post method.

Comment: @Polochon  I also tried without stringify but problem was same

Comment: @Polochon without stringify I get request like : { '{\n  "que": {\n    "id": 1,\n    "status": 1\n}': '' }

Comment: Why are you passing in JSON but setting it as x-www-form-urlencoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem's i see here are "stringify". You don't need to pass stringified JSON to the Node API POST body and the other one is headers mark Content-Type headers as "application/json" or you can remove the headers.append. by default it takes Content-Type as application/json.

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` OR `Content-Type: application/json`. Sending a JSON (double encoded) as `x-www-form-urlencoded` wouldn't work.

That said, just use `Content-Type: application/json` (will be interpreted by `bodyparser.json()`-middleware) and do not double-encode json values.

```
var data = {
  // ...
};

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // application/json is always UTF-8
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

return this._http.post(url, questionData, options)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```